# Haskell - Convert integer to double, then String

Tags: haskell, type-conversion

I'm practicing Haskell by writing a program that will convert a price in cents into dollars. Obviously, this means that my Int will need to become a Double, but I want my final output to be that of a String. My code:

First, I defined my `Price` type:

`type Price = Int`

Then, I wrote my module:

```
formatDollars :: Price -> String
formatDollars x = show (fromIntegral (x `div` 100))
```

My test input for `x` was 188, which should give me 1.88.

But my output is always `"1"`. This makes me think that my fromIntegral function might not be utilized correctly in my code, as if it's truncating after the decimal. Since I'm so new to Haskell, I'm sure it's a  simple mistake; could someone help me out?

Comment: `div` is integer division, so from that point, the value is *gone*.

Comment: It's not so obvious it should ever be a `Double`; in fact, you should probably use a [Data.Fixed.Centi](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Fixed.html#t:Centi).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
188 `div` 100 == 1
```

You want to convert to `Double` *before* doing the division. (And then do real division, not integer division.)

```
formatDollars x = show ((fromIntegral x) / 100)
```

Answer (score 6):

`div` is *integer* division. So that means that `div 188 100`, you get:

```
Prelude> div 188 100
1
```

So that means that after the `div`, the `88` is "gone". Furthermore `div` truncates to negative infinity. As a result if the number is negative we get:

```
Prelude> div (-210) 100
-3
```

But you probably better do not convert the number to a `Float` anyway: `Float`s are not capable to precisely represent decimal numbers: approximations are used. For example if you write `0.82`, a value will be stored that looks like `0.8200000000000001` (although this is again not the exact representation). In case the number is rather large, the mantissa is not always capable to represent the entire number, so there can be an error in the conversion. Finally if you print small or large numbers, by default `show` will use scientific notation (this is of course not "inherently" a problem, but I think it is rather odd if you print a price, I've never seen a supermarket with labels like `$ 9e-2`):

```
Prelude> 0.01 :: Float
1.0e-2
```

Which is probably not what you want.

You can simply split the number in three parts: the value before the decimal dot, and the two digits after the decimal dot. Like:

```
import Data.Char(intToDigit)

formatDollars :: Price -> String
formatDollars pr = show pr0 ++ ['.', pr1, pr2]
    where pr0 = quot pr 100
          digit n = intToDigit (abs (rem n 10))
          pr1 = digit (quot pr 10)
          pr2 = digit pr
```

The [**`Decimal`** [hackage]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Decimal) package might also be an option. A `DecimalRaw` is represented in such a way that for the *decimal* system, it can represent numbers precisely. For example:

```
Prelude> import Data.Decimal
Prelude Data.Decimal> Decimal 2 188
1.88
```

So we can avoid all the trouble, and write it like:

```
import Data.Decimal(DecimalRaw(Decimal))

formatDollars :: Price -> String
formatDollars = show . Decimal 2
```

Comment: I believe there's some number formatting stuff in `Numeric` (?) as well...

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid: yes like `showHFloat`, but I do not really like the `RealFoat` constraint here, since then again we are in the "floating point" world. Especially for prices, calculating with floating points can result in summing up values to values that not completely correct.